# Convert hour to PM and AM with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a timestamp in PHP, so I'm using Carbon extension to manage everything that is related with date, time,etc. Now I have for example a hour *23:00* or *20:00* with this extension how I can convert that to AM and PM format?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a out-of-the-box helper method for this, but you could always use the `format` method, which defers to the base class method [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Example:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
echo $now->format('g:i A');
```

This will echo out something like 5:17 PM.

The `g`, `i`, and `A` can seem random, but the list of parameters can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`g`: 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

`i`: Minutes with leading zeros

`A`: Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem